# ESP32 ROS unable to sync

Tags: esp32

I am trying the example [ros arduino publisher](http://wiki.ros.org/rosserial_arduino/Tutorials/Hello%20World) using an [ESP32 Dev Module](https://www.amazon.ca/gp/product/B07Z9VSXVP/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_asin_title_o03_s01?ie=UTF8&psc=1).
When I try to connect using rosserial I get "Uable to sync" error.
I have tried using different baud rates, 115200, 57600 and 9600
None of them worked. I clicked on the serial port monitor of the arduino IDE by mistake and saw this message:

```
Rebooting...
ets Jul 29 2019 12:21:46

rst:0xc (SW_CPU_RESET),boot:0x13 (SPI_FAST_FLASH_BOOT)
configsip: 0, SPIWP:0xee
clk_drv:0x00,q_drv:0x00,d_drv:0x00,cs0_drv:0x00,hd_drv:0x00,wp_drv:0x00
mode:DIO, clock div:1
load:0x3fff0018,len:4
load:0x3fff001c,len:1100
load:0x40078000,len:9232
load:0x40080400,len:6400
entry 0x400806a8
```

Not sure what to make out of the above error.
What am I doing wrong?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: That's not an error. That's just the normal boot sequence.

Comment: This message keeps on repeating itself. Does this mean it keeps on rebooting?

Comment: Sounds like it, yes. It's a software reboot, so some code is telling it to reboot.

Comment: It's a standard code, what can go wrong with that?